# How to open 3 different links, that is a different link each time on cycle on 3 clicks in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

I need a logic to loop 3 URLs on the cycle of 3 clicks . like after every 3rd click I want the link to be changed . .

```
   {
        if(Get_Cookie("pagecount") % 3 === 0)
        self.location.href="https://www.google.com";
        else
        self.location.href="https://www.wikipedia.com"";
   }
```

This is the logic I used to loop two different links on third click. but I need three different links to cycle. Here ,Get_Cookie("pagecount") returns the number of times I'm clicking the URL
on the next three clicks I want

```
self.location.href="https://www.facebook.com"";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the links in an array, and cycle through that. This has the benefit of being able to add as many links to the array as you want.

```js
const links = ["https://www.google.com","https://www.facebook.com","https://www.stackoverflow.com"];
const timesToRepeat = 3;

let clickCount = 0;

document.getElementById("btn").onclick = (e) => {
  console.log(links[Math.floor(clickCount / timesToRepeat) % links.length]);
  clickCount += 1;
};
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```